# How do I solve "Too few arguments to function" in function Laravel, with VueJS and applying DOMPDF?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dompdf

I am making an application for a Lab with Laravel and VueJS, in which I want to make PDF documents of reports. For this, I installed DOMPDF. 
When I try to execute the method in VueJS, for open the PDF, I get the following error:
`"Too few arguments to function App \ Http \ Controllers \ SampleController :: reportShow (), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"`
What am I doing wrong?
From already thank you very much

`MuestraController:`

```
public function informeMuestra(Request $request,$id){
    $id = $request->id;
    $muestra = Muestra::join('remitentes', 'remitentes.id', '=', 'muestras.remitente_id')
                ->join('solicitantes', 'solicitantes.id', '=', 'muestras.solicitante_id')
                ->join('localidads', 'localidads.id', '=', 'muestras.localidad_id')
                ->select('muestras.*', 'remitentes.nombre as nombre_remitente', 'solicitantes.nombre as nombre_solicitante', 'solicitantes.direccion as direccion_sol', 'localidads.localidad')
                ->where('muestras.id', '=', $id)->take(1)->get();
    $pedidos = EnsayoMuestra::join('ensayos', 'ensayo_muestra.ensayo_id', '=', 'ensayos.id')
                ->join('muestras', 'ensayo_muestra.muestra_id', '=', 'muestras.id')
                ->select('ensayo_muestra.*', 'ensayos.ensayo as ensayo', 'ensayos.metodo as metodo', 'ensayos.unidades as unidades')
                ->where('ensayo_muestra.muestra_id', '=',$id)
                ->orderBy('ensayo_muestra.id', 'asc')->get();

    $num_muestra=Muestra::select('numero')->where('id',$id)->get();

    $informe = \PDF::loadView('pdf.informemuestra',['muestra'=>$muestra,'pedidos'=>$pedidos]);
    return $informe->stream('muestra-'.$num_muestra[0]->numero.'.pdf');
```

`Muestra.vue:`

```
cargarInforme(id){
            window.open('http://localhost/dsa/public/muestra/informeMuestra?id' + id + ',' + '_blank');
        },
```

`Route (web.php):`

```
Route::get('/muestra/informeMuestra/{id}', 'MuestraController@informeMuestra')->name('muestra_pdf');
```

Comment: please show your `SampleController` firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the only solution that worked for me was the following:

window.open('http://localhost/dsa/public/muestra/informeMuestra/' + id);